# How to unit test DBService which uses the Servicestack Funq IOC

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, ormlite-servicestack, servicestack-ioc

I am new to a project which I should extend so I decided to use TDD to quickly recognize any problems of a system I do not fully understand.

There is one class called `DBService` which "encapsulates" all the db access. For example there is one method called `getAllCustomers` which returns a list of `Customers`. This would look something like this (this is just an example for a better understanding):

```
public class DBService
{
    public IDbConnectionFactory DBFactory { 
        get { return DI.Container.Resolve<IDbConnectionFactory>(); }
    }

    public List<Customer> GetAllCustomers()
    {
        try
        {
            using (var connection = DBFactory.OpenDbConnection())
            {
                var dbResult = connection.Select<Customer>();
                // code ommitted
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // code ommitted
        }
    }      
}
```

Another problem is that at start (in the ServiceStack `AppHost.Configure`) all tables are created if they do not exist, and for some tables if they exists some columns etc are added (which are probably changes which were added later)

When I now for example have to extend the customer and add another field, addresses I would like to do that in TDD style but I have no idea how.

1. I cannot inject any `DBFactory` since the getter is private
2. Afaik I cannot use the `:memory:` connection string for the `OrmLiteConnectionFactory` because I am using ServiceStack 3.9.74

So what are my options here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoid the Service Locator anti-pattern and use constructor injection instead. Try to stay away from using DI containers directly in dependent classes. It tightly couples your classes to concerns that don't belong there and make it difficult to test classes in isolation.

```
public class DBService {
    private readonly IDbConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

    public DBService(IDbConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        this.connectionFactory = connectionFactory;
    }

    public IDbConnectionFactory DBFactory { get { return connectionFactory; } }

    public List<Customer> GetAllCustomers() {
        try {
            using (var connection = DBFactory.OpenDbConnection()) {
                var dbResult = connection.Select<Customer>();
                //... code omitted for brevity
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //... code omitted for brevity
        }
    }
}
```

Both `Select<T>` and `OpenDbConnection` look like extension methods. I would suggest checking what their expectatiosn are and mock those behaviors as well.

If `DbService` is itself to be used as a dependency for other class then that class should be abstracted as well.

```
public interface IDbService {
    IDbConnectionFactory DBFactory { get; }
    List<Customer> GetAllCustomers();
}
```

and have the implementation inherit

```
public class DbService : IDbService { 
    //... code removed for brevity
}
```

and make sure to register everything with the IoC container.

Comment: yes I agree, the service-locator anti-pattern is something I should try to avoid. I just thought that there is an easier way without much refactoring for now.

Comment: That is the thing with [Technical debt](https://www.google.com/search?q=technical+debt). It always calls in the loan.